Perforce Error "must refer to client" when submitting on newly setup server
Submit validation failed -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 16'.
    'check-case' validation failed: Exception during trigger execution: <class 'P4.P4Exception'> [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 dirs //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/config/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/source/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/characters/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/cursor/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/levelprototyping/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/startercontent/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/__externalactors__/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/__externalobjects__/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/blueprints/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/input/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/maps/* //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/input/actions/*" )
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/config/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/source/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/characters/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/cursor/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/levelprototyping/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/startercontent/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/__externalactors__/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/__externalobjects__/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/blueprints/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/input/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/maps/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
        [Error]: "//koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/input/actions/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'."
     <traceback object at 0x7f909845f300>
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/config/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/source/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/characters/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/cursor/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/levelprototyping/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/startercontent/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/__externalactors__/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/__externalobjects__/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/blueprints/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/input/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/maps/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    P4 ERROR: //koboldkitchendepot/koboldkitchen/content/topdown/input/actions/*/... - must refer to client 'vmss-prod-commit-funkstudios-rrwleOH3707'.
    An error was encountered during trigger execution. Please
    contact your Perforce administrator and ask them to
    investigate the cause of this error in /p4/1/logs/p4triggers.log


Getting this error everytime I try to submit checked out files in the P4V client. I was able to push up my first project files successfully, however, afterwards nothing worked.
I created a new folder in the depot separate from my project and wasn't able to push it up. Also tried from a new workspace and didn't work. However, some files just work and I literally don't know why.

Your Perforce server appears to have a "check-case" trigger that isn't working properly.

@MichaelLiu Yea I see that too, but it means very little to me besides being a trigger I see in p4admin. I created the server through the Azure Marketplace so I'm confused as to why it's failing because I can't even remove the trigger or edit the trigger or view the trigger. If anything I've discovered that I can edit files and submit but just can't add new files and submit those for whatever reason.

I think I've found the issue, although I don't necessarily have a solution yet as I'm dealing with the same thing. The file structure of your logs reveal you're using Unreal Engine, and you mentioned you set up the perforce server using Azure Marketplace (assuming Helix Core Cloud) and it sounds like you didn't edit anything.
Basically one of the defaults checked when doing the server setup - something you cannot change post-deployment - is the case sensitivity which is determined by if your server is hosted on windows or linux. They tell you not to touch it and keep it case sensitive unless you know you need it turned off. Well, turns out one of the things that specifically needs case sensitivity turned off is certain unreal files, but it's pretty hard to know that in the first place and they don't tell you that Unreal doesn't work on case-sensitive systems.
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/case-sensitivity-and-platforms.html?Highlight=case%20insensitive
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/unreal-engine-does-not-support-running-from-case-sensitive-file-systems/488322
Unfortunately, Perforce's only comments on this is "You cannot change the setting after you select it during sign up". We may be SOL.
EDIT Can confirm, Perforce support has told me that the only thing I can do is re-provision my Helix Core and start over from scratch.
